# No SpringExtension.class

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to setup Spring Boot + JUnit5... So by tutorials I could get so `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.contedevel.virto</groupId>
    <artifactId>users</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>users</name>
    <description>Virto users service</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.0.2</junit-jupiter.version>
        <junit-platform.version>1.0.0</junit-platform.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For connection pooling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And tried to make a test:

```
ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void register() {
    }
}
```

But there is not the `SpringExtension.class`, I can't import it.

```
Error:(7, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringExtension
```

How to fix my `pom.xml` or maybe can I use a some another class?
**P.S.** I'm a noobie in the Spring so my question may be stupid but I can't get how to resolve.

Comment: Your facing any issue, or you want to know what is the use of `SpringExtension.class in junit`

Comment: @ArvindKatte I have errors

Comment: spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT use this artifact

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with the version of Spring Boot. You are providing         **1.5.9.RELEASE**, but that class is provided from Spring 5 (according to [SpringExtension](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit/jupiter/SpringExtension.html)), so try to use newer version of Spring Boot like         **2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT** or another extension like [that one](https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5).

Answer (score 4):

Your `spring-boot` version `1.5.9.RELEASE` will not support `Junit 5`. Please change the spring-boot version to `spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`

Add the below line to your pom.xml

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 1):

I Had a similar issue and it turns out the jar file, located at `~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-test/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar` was **corrupt**. I had to *delete* the jar and refresh `pom.xml`